# What's the difference between .data, .symtab in an ELF file?

Tags: file, linker, elf, objdump, readelf

My understanding is that .data stores the initialized global variables of the program. But isn't that what .symtab stores as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But isn't that what .symtab stores as well?

No. The `.symtab` is a *table of symbols* (usually examined with `nm` command); its contents has *nothing* to do with the contents of global variables.

It does *describe* global and static variables and functions, and also can be completely removed without loss of functionality of the original binary.